# Sahi pro test suite running one test case only

Tags: javascript, sahi

I'm new to sahi pro I want to run the test suite with two test cases.

I'm giving two test case in the Test2.suite and started to run by giving the command `testrunner.bat <sahi suite file name> <start url> <browser type>`

The problem is that it is running the second case only. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you giving two test cases in the suite? I hope your Test2.suite is something like this:

```
test_script1.sah // script for first test case
test_script2.sah // script for second test case
```

When you run this using testrunner, your reports will show you the result for Test2.suite. When you click on the name, you can see the results for both the scripts individually.

Also, if you can mention the version of Sahi OS or Sahi Pro you are using, I can check for that particular version.

thanks,
Vivek